# Alternative Way To Animate Instead Of 'UIView.animate'

Tags: swift, xcode

When using this method to animate, it will stop the animation if the phone is locked then reopened or if the app is switched away from and then switched back to.

I have a StackView Titled "MainFocusStack" that I'm animating:

```
    //AnimationSizeLOOP
 UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 10, delay: 0, options: [ .autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
 UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 1.0) { self.mainFocusLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3) }
   })
```

What can I do to remedy this?

**edit**

This animation, and 2 others of similar code (one for glow and another for opacity), are synced with a counter. In the above code it grows for 10 seconds and falls for 10 seconds in synced with the timer.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply start the animation when the app comes back into the foreground, e.g., let us imagine that you moved this animation code to some function:

```swift
func startAnimation() {
    subview.transform = .identity
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [ .autoreverse, .repeat]) { [self] in
        subview.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    }
}
```

Then you could start this not only in `viewDidLoad`, but also whenever the app becomes active, by observing `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification`, e.g.:

```swift
private var observer: NSObjectProtocol?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureSubview()

    observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
        self?.startAnimation()
    }
}

deinit {
    if let observer = observer {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
    }
}
```

---

If you are looking for alternative, `UIViewPropertyAnimator` can be paused and resumed, picking up from where it left off:

```swift
private let subview = ...
private var didBecomeActiveObserver: NSObjectProtocol?
private var willResignActiveObserver: NSObjectProtocol?
private var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureSubview()

    didBecomeActiveObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
        self?.animator?.startAnimation()
    }

    willResignActiveObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
        self?.animator?.pauseAnimation()
    }

    startAnimation(from: .identity, to: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3))
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(didBecomeActiveObserver!)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(willResignActiveObserver!)
}

func startAnimation(from: CGAffineTransform, to: CGAffineTransform) {
    animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear]) {
        self.subview.transform = to
    } completion: { [weak self] position in
        self?.startAnimation(from: to, to: from)
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this would restart the animation, right? In my case that would de-sync it from other elements so I may need to try something else

Comment: Yes, it restarts it. Perhaps you can edit question to give simple example of what you are synchronizing it with. Alternative animation mechanisms are [`UIViewPropertyAnimator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator), `CAAnimation`, or `CADisplayLink` manual animations.

Comment: I've shown example of the former, but without knowing precisely what other elements are being animated, the timing likely isn't going to match up perfectly. If you need them perfectly coordinated, manual animations with `CADisplayLink` may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better *not* to want to resume the animation from where it was when it went into the background. If you really do insist on that, then it's your responsibility to take care of this. When you go into the background, remember where you are in the animation. When you come back to the foreground, start the animation from that point of the animation.

Your "place" within the animation (often referred to as the *current frame*) is signified by the animated layer's `timeOffset`, or the `timeOffset` of the animation object itself. If you're using a UIViewPropertyAnimator, you can use its `fractionComplete`.